# C# how to total counter ip in list

Tags: c#, ip, counter

I want to count the number of unique IP addresses in the system.

example :

> - 127.0.0.1:80 > 1.1.1.1:xxx
> - 127.0.0.1:80 > 1.1.1.1:xxx
> - 127.0.0.1:80 > 1.1.1.1:xxx
> - 127.0.0.1:80 > 1.1.1.1:xxx
> - 127.0.0.1:80 > 1.1.1.1:xxx
> - 127.0.0.1:80 > 1.1.1.1:xxx
> - 127.0.0.1:80 > 1.1.1.2:xxx
> - 127.0.0.1:80 > 1.1.1.3:xxx
> - 127.0.0.1:80 > 1.1.1.4:xxx

can counter show `1.1.1.1(6), 1.1.1.2(1), 1.1.1.3(1), 1.1.1.4(1)`

This my code:

thankyou

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        do
        {
          monitor();
          System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
        } while (true);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static void monitor()
    {
        string serverMonitor = "127.0.0.1:80";

        IPGlobalProperties ipProperties = IPGlobalProperties.GetIPGlobalProperties();
        IPEndPoint[] endPoints = ipProperties.GetActiveTcpListeners();
        TcpConnectionInformation[] tcpConnections = ipProperties.GetActiveTcpConnections();

        foreach (TcpConnectionInformation info in tcpConnections)
        {
            string list = info.LocalEndPoint.Address.ToString() + ":" + info.LocalEndPoint.Port.ToString();
            string remote = info.RemoteEndPoint.Address.ToString() + ":" + info.RemoteEndPoint.Port.ToString();

            if (list == serverMonitor)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(list + " > " + remote + " [" + info.State.ToString() + "]");
            }
        }          
        Console.WriteLine("--------------------------------------------------");
    }
```

Comment: You don't know how to use `List<string>` ?

Comment: hello I'm a beginner c #

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just count them and store in dictionary.

```
Dictionary<string, int> ips = new Dictionary<string, int>();

// ...

foreach (var info in tcpConnections)
{
    string list = info.LocalEndPoint.Address.ToString() + ":" + info.LocalEndPoint.Port.ToString();
    string remote = info.RemoteEndPoint.Address.ToString() + ":" + info.RemoteEndPoint.Port.ToString();
    if (list == serverMonitor)
    {
        if (ips.ContainsKey(remote))
            ips[remote]++;
        else 
            ips.Add(remote, 1);
    }
}

foreach (var entry in ips)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} ({1})", entry.Key, entry.Value);
}
```